# Determine where to apply inverse variance weighting

Tags: variance, weighted-mean

I have a 2D input signal (x,y) that is governed by noise of different nature( white, poisson, other residual noises that are difficult to quantify - pink is cleaned). The stDev may (but can also look completely different) look like this:

[image: stDev small area]

As you can see there is a clear gradient. I thus want to weigh my read out signal with an inverse variance weighting.

To help understand, this is how the whole image of the std - errormap looks like:
[image: stDev whole image]

I am looking for a method that cancels the weighting in areas where noise is fairly constant. My first approach was doing something like

```
 if stDev(stDev(n*m)) < abs (mean(stDev(neighboring n*m) - stDev(n*m))
    no weighting
```

However this is than subject to fine tuning the size of the field n*m so that it fits  which a) makes it pretty arbitrary and b) will not work in general.

Would taking the median/mean of the whole field be a better solution? - I fail to see how the median is a meaningful quantity when the noise is made up of different components?

Any idea on how to do that. 
I do have the input signal available and could use this to determine the regions with high poisson noise level. I am trying to avoid that because it is hard to estimate the white noise level + other noise level (the other noise can i.e. result from "pointing errors", which depend on a variety of factors)

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "a method that cancels the weighting"? That you want lower weights where the standard deviation is lower? Or lower weights where the standard deviation is, itself , exhibiting less variation?

Comment: bye canceling i mean that it sets the weights to 1, thus not weighting at all. I think it doesn't make sense to do an error weight where the noise is predominantly white

Comment: My current approach is to take a **large field** where the stdev is "well behaved" but including the areas where none white noise is dominant := **whole-field** - from this field I calculate the **median** (seams appropriate as I want the high noise areas not to dominate).

I compare this with **averages of small n*m subfields**. If the averages of the subfield minus median of the whole-field is smaller than the stdev of the whole field: set weights to 1.
       `if abs(average_subfield-median_whole-field) < stdev_whole-field:
             set weights 1`
arguably this is a terrible mess.

Comment: I do not think this has anything much to do with meta-analysis so I removed the tag but feel free to revert the edit if you disagree.